# How to convert Java Date object to Matlab datetime array with time zone

Tags: java, matlab, datetime

I use a program that returns data whose timestamp is in [Java date objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html). I need to read the time in Matlab and to be able to do datetime arithmetics with datetime arrays generated in Matlab that may have time zone specified. How do you convert a Java Date object to Matlab datetime array with time zone?

I have been trying to use [Java time serial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime--). But I can't get the time zone correct in Matlab.

For example, it is ~2:30 pm EST now and the [`now`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/now.html) function in Matlab works as intended.

```
>> datetime(now,'ConvertFrom','datenum','TimeZone','America/New_York')
ans = 
  datetime
   06-Feb-2020 14:37:40
```

However, starting with Java time serial, which is time since 1970/1/1 GMT in miliseconds, the same line doesn't work. A date object for 10:40 am EST returns the following.

```
>> class(JavaDateObj)
ans =
    'java.util.Date'    
>> format long
>> JavaDateObj.getTime
ans =
     1.581003592273000e+12
% to run this snippet, ignore the above; set JavaDateSerial = 1.581003592273000e+12; and replace JavaDateObj.getTime below with JavaDateSerial


%%%% expecting time in EST below and get time in GMT instead

>> datetime(datenum([1970 1 1 0 0 JavaDateObj.getTime/1000]),'ConvertFrom','datenum','TimeZone','America/New_York')
ans = 
  datetime
   06-Feb-2020 15:39:52

%%%% expecting now to be later than earlier but get the wrong result

>> temp=ans;
>> datetime(now,'ConvertFrom','datenum','TimeZone','America/New_York') > temp
ans =
  logical
   0
```

If using date serial is the way to make the above conversion work, how do you incorporate time zone in Matlab from a Java time serial?

If there is another way to convert from Java date object to Matlab datetime array with time zone, please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getTime` method of `java.util.Date` [returns the milliseconds in GMT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime--), but the `datenum` constructor takes milliseconds in local time. You need to convert to a GMT time first, and then convert the time zone as a second step.

```
dt = datetime(datenum([1970 1 1 0 0 JavaDateObj.getTime/1000]),'ConvertFrom','datenum');
dt.TimeZone = 'GMT';
dt.TimeZone = 'America/New_York';
```

If you specify the `TimeZone` in the original constructor call, you're telling Matlab that the datenum value you're sending is a local time that's already in that time zone.

You can also simplify your constructor call by using the "posixtime" conversion format, which is closer to what the `java.util.Date.getTime()` returns.

```
dt = datetime(datenum(javaDateObj.getTime/1000),'ConvertFrom','posixtime')
```

Comment: Oh, yeah: try the 'posixtime' date format instead of 'datenum' for a simpler constructor call.

Answer (score 1):

Best to not involve datenum. In MATLAB since R2018b, there's a direct conversion:

```
>> format long g
>> t = 1.581003592273000e+12
t =
         1581003592273
>> dt = datetime(t,'convertFrom','epochtime','TicksPerSecond',1000,'TimeZone','UTC','Format','dd-MMM-uuuu HH:mm:ss.SSS z')
dt = 
  datetime
   06-Feb-2020 15:39:52.273 UTC
>> dt.TimeZone = 'America/New_York'
dt = 
  datetime
   06-Feb-2020 10:39:52.273 EST
```

t is millis since 1970 UTC, so to get a local timestamp, you create a UTC datetime and then change the timezone.

Prior to R2018b, you can do this:

```
>> dt = datetime(t/1000,'convertFrom','posixtime','TimeZone','UTC','Format','dd-MMM-uuuu HH:mm:ss.SSS z')
dt = 
  datetime
   06-Feb-2020 15:39:52.273 UTC
>> dt.TimeZone = 'America/New_York'
dt = 
  datetime
   06-Feb-2020 10:39:52.273 EST
```

Comment: Nvm. Didn't realize the format part is just for display.